# How to Async load js contents in a DIV element which has document.write?

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

i have js file `jsfile.js` which has the code

```
document.write('<script>..</script><style>..</style><a></a><script src".."></script>');
```

The code inside the document.write() is actually an html document of a sample webpage with scripts , styles , metas and all other possible elements.

Without render blocking, how do i load the `jsfile.js` inside a `div` element in my webpage?

I currently use `<script src="https://example.com/jsfile.js"></script>`, but it will render block other contents which comes below the `script`.

Comment: You really don't want to be using `document.write`. That stopped being useful around the middle ages. It has numerous issues. Instead DOM-inject your code or use a templating library.

Comment: Do you have the option of changing `jsfile.js`? If so, that would be *by far* the best thing to do.

Comment: Is this an external script then, different origin? If not, and there really is no other option - then I'd try and have document.write go into an iframe first maybe, and then grab the actual content from there.